# when i release an NSMutableArray that i allocate and initiate, my code breaks

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

with this code, i want to add an image at the place the user taps. i want to add a new one for each tap.

```
-(void) foundDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{       
    UIView *piece = recognizer.view;
    CGPoint locationInView = [recognizer locationInView:piece];

    UIImageView *testPoint = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inner-circle.png"]];
    testPoint.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    testPoint.center = CGPointMake(locationInView.x, locationInView.y);
    [self.imageView addSubview:testPoint];

    NSMutableArray *tempTestPointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:testPointArray];
    [tempTestPointArray addObject:testPoint];
    testPointArray = tempTestPointArray;

    NSLog(@"testPointArray: %@", testPointArray);

    CGRect myRect = CGRectMake((testPoint.center.x + 12), (testPoint.center.y + 12), 10, 10);

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Point %d", [testPointArray count]];
    myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:10];
    [myLabel sizeToFit];
    [imageView addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];

    [testPoint release];
    //[tempTestPointArray release];
}
```

why is it that when i release tempTestPointArray, my code breaks when i implement a second tap? it crashes on:

```
NSMutableArray *tempTestPointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:testPointArray];
```

when i comment out the release for it, the Analyzer does not flag it as a leak. what happened to the rule, if you alloc/init it, you have to release it?

EDIT: adding .h file

.h file:

```
@interface TestPointMapViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    //other code
    NSArray *testPointArray;
}
//other code
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *testPointArray;
//other code
@end
```

and then @synthesize testPointArray in .m file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `testPointArray` is not assigning to a property, it is a plain ivar. Doing the line

```
testPointArray = tempTestPointArray;
```

Is leaking whatever is previously in `testPointArray`. Declare `testPointArray` as a retained property and change to.

```
self.testPointArray = tempTestPointArray;
```

Then keep the `[tempTestPointArray release];`

EDIT:

So the reason why this code is failing has to do with the magic of properties. The following code is equivalent.

```
self.testPointArray = tempTestPointArray;
[self setTestPointArray:tempTestPointArray];
```

When you do the `@sythesize testPointArray;` it is generating a setter method similar to this:

```
- (void)setTestPointArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    id temp = testPointArray;
    testPointArray = [array retain];
    [temp release];
}
```

So when you don't use the property notation `self.testPointArray` you are not retaining the variable correctly. You are also losing a reference to a retained object, which is now a leak.

That make sense? If not please review this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

Comment: testPointArray is a instance variable: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *testPointArray;.  is that the retained you refer to?

Comment: Yes, that is it. testPointArray, the property, is backed by an ivar of the same name. You have to use the property notation in order for it to get retained properly.

Comment: right, so change testPointArray = tempTestPointArray; to self.testPointArray = tempTestPointArray;

Comment: awesome, that worked, thank you very much, i appreciate it. now just gotta understand the logic of why it worked =D

Comment: so anytime i use instance variables, i need to add the "self" so it uses the @synthetic setter which will properly use retain/release. got it, thanks again!

Comment: correct, always use your property notation unless you know what you are doing